# in scrollviewed page, can not reach (scroll) listview element in android (mono)

Tags: android, listview, uiscrollview, xamarin.android, scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:text="Mesaj Başlığı"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textExtendHeader"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="000dp">
                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fillViewport="true"
                        android:gravity="top">
                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/ListC"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
                            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
                            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:scrollingCache="true"
                            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                            android:stackFromBottom="false"
                            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
                    </ScrollView>
                </TableRow>
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="135dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">
                <View
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="135dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">
                <View
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            </FrameLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:showDividers="middle">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="72dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Çağrı Bilgileri"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textExtendHeader"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:textSize="22sp" />
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="33dp"
                            android:layout_x="0dp"
                            android:layout_y="135dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">
                            <View
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                        </FrameLayout>
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Mesaj Başlığı"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textExtendHeader"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:textSize="22sp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:text="mesaj içeriği"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:id="@+id/textExtendBody" />
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Tarih"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/textExtendDatetime" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="72dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:id="@+id/avatarView3"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout15"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Effective Navigation in Android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/item_text_primary3"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:text="James Montemagno"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/item_text_primary4" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="72dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:id="@+id/avatarView4"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout16"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Mastering Time and Space"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/item_text_primary7"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Jérémie Laval"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/item_text_primary8" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout full page scrollview, i got a listview on this page too, but when i use scrollview can not move or scroll listview rows, is there any sample? i try to use listview header and footer but i couldnt success any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your layout. You have three Object with scrolling which you set inside each other. Try to avoid ListView inside ScrollView. In this case you have a problem that system can't understand where to catch your touch and scroll after that on screen. Your ListView is a nested element of ScrollView. ListView always sets focus on his parent, that's why it can't scroll.

Comment: oh thanks, i removed scrollview of before listview, now i got one scrollview and one listview but i wish to scroll page but if user check latest news just scroll listview if touch other place listview get scrolls with whole page.. i searched some , i got footer and header of listview but it get more complex for me, is there an easy way ?

Comment: @ichwill You didn't get my point. Delete ScrollView that contains ListView. ListView should not be in ScrollView. 
As I know generate footer and header - then it's easier to fix nested ListView in ScrollView.
In another case you can set height or weight to your ListView. And under it you can set ScrollView for news. I know it is not exactly what you want but it is a variant.

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest Listview, inside ScrollView. Listview will allow scrolling by default.
And since you nested listview inside the scrollview, listview is not able to get events. Hence, you are not able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a ListView in a ScrollView in a ScrollView, pick one!

Your ListView is already scrollable and handles view recycling automatically so that should work fine by itself.

Comment: oh thanks, i removed scrollview of before listview, now i got one scrollview and one listview but i wish to scroll page but if user check latest news just scroll listview if touch other place listview get scrolls with whole page.. i searched some , i got footer and header of listview but it get more complex for me, is there an easy way ?